# Can't send large text chat message from quickblox

Tags: java, android, webrtc, quickblox

I'm using quickblox for both of android and web web application. I'm looking for a way to send a large text message from quickblox.

Do I want to split text message into multiple small messages and merge those from opponent end or is there any other way to send a large message through quickblox.

Comment: what do you mean by 'large' message (how many symbols)? an attachment of a large size?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what in my mind:

1. Split a message into smaller chunks and send them
2. Create an attach, simple text file, upload it to Content module and send a link to other user to this file

More about file attachments here

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Send_and_receive_a_message_with_attachment

And how to work with Content module

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-ios

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have achieve this by using attachment. By send large text as a attachment and convert it back to string in other end.